# Solaris - How to tell whether machine is running SPARC or Intel Chip

Tags: unix, solaris, unix-shell, sunos

What command can I run to tell whether SunOS 5.10 is running a SPARC or Intel chip?

Comment: Don't use people as a search engine.

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 3):

run "uname -p".  sparc will say "sparc", intel will say "i386".  Alternately, run "prtdiag -v" and look at the cpu section.

Comment: What if it says `x86_64`?